# Zeroes of a non elementary integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, roots

How would one find the zeroes in such cases? I tried some geometric approximations using the graph to no avail.

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln \left(x + \sin t \right)dt$$

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean zeroes of $F(x)=\int_0^x \ln(x+\sin t)dt$?

Comment: Not really, the limits are well defined and there is only one variable term which is "x"

Comment: For one thing $x\ge 1$ for the integrand to have real values in range $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: I agree, I'm sure the root lies in between 1 and 2

Comment: @User1300135 I wrote an answer, I am not sure if it is a function in term of x or t. I supposed its a function in term of x

Comment: I did this on a computer and the answer is 1.25.

Comment: @shere it's a function of x, but the integral is in respect to t.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the integral as a function of $x$ and then differentiate with respect to $x$. This yields $$f'(x)=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{x+\sin t}\,dt$$ which can be easily solved by a tangent half angle substitution to yield $$f'(x)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$$
Integrating with respect to $x$ yields $f(x)=2\pi\cosh^{-1}(x)+C.$

To solve for $C,$ consider $f(1).$ The integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln (1+\sin x)\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln (1+\cos x)\,dx=2\pi\ln(2)+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln (\cos^2 (x/2))\,dx\\=2\pi\ln(2)+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln (\sin^2 (x/2))\,dx=2\pi\ln(2)+4\int_0^{\pi}\ln (\sin (x))\,dx,$$ which upon combining with the famous result $\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin(x))=-\pi\ln(2),$ and $f(1)=C,$ yields $C=-2\pi\ln2$. And lo and behold, $\ln 2= \cosh^{-1}(5/4)!!$ This immediately yields $x=\frac54.$

Comment: no the bound of integral is not related to x, your derivative is wrong

Comment: @shere I am finding the function as a function of $x$, and the first integral is indeed done with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 1):

For $1 < x < 2$, the integral seems to be
$$ -\pi\, \left( 2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -3\,\ln  \left( x+\sqrt {{x}^{2
}-1} \right) -\ln  \left( x-\sqrt {{x}^{2}-1} \right)  \right) 
$$
and this is $0$ at $x = 5/4$.

Comment: How do you compute this integral? Can you give an outline of the technique?

Comment: This seems right, how did you solve it? I've been searching for weeks but got nothing.